# Several conditions on different columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have table 1 have master data , and i want to fill stock column of table 2 after performing the following conditions :
id of table 2  equal to id table 1 AND
Size of table 2 equal to size of table 1 AND
Color of table 2  equal to color of table 1

[Here is snapshot of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN0ru.png)

[Here is snapshot of what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDCNA.png)

which is wrong so please state the formula to be used that meet 3 conditions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now what your function is doing:
if every ID is 100 AND every ID is black AND every size is xl then show me the whole column Stock (result will be an array).

Try using Sumifs:
=SUMIFS(Table1[Stock],Table1[ID],F3,Table1[Color],G3, etc.